# Sikaflex self leveling sealant keeps draining

Tags: basement, waterproofing, sealing, driveway, joints

I’m trying to fill a gap between my driveway and foundation wall to stop basement water leak. Per inspector’s recommendation I applied some Sikaflex self leveling sealant on top of backer rod.

It’s not a very big area, maybe 8 linear feet, but at this point I’ve applied five (!!!) 29 oz tubes and the stuff continues to “drain” into hidden holes instead of staying level. How do I get it to stop doing that and actually be level with driveway surface?

I asked ChatGPT and it suggested patching the holes with masking tape and then applying more sealant. Would that actually work?

Comment: Probably. Where is it going?

Comment: your  backer rod is to small, it has to be pressed in

Comment: @asinine With 5 tubes of the sealant already applied, how would you recommend I dam the holes before applying more?

Comment: did you had to hard press the backer rod to get it in

Comment: Are there any obvious spots where it’s draining? How far are you below the level you want?

Comment: Also, you can try a non-leveling sealant first—just make sure it's not flush with the surface.  That may help seal any holes or gaps you have in your backer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backer rod is undersized, or there there are gaps in the concrete that the backer rod isn’t able to expand into. A good fit on a backer rod is usually quite tight, requiring effort to squish and push into the void. Using tape is usually good advice with levelling compounds, but you're unlikely to get a good seal with tape in this situation.

If you can’t get a larger backer rod, or it was already a tight fit, use a thicker sealant on top of the backer to plug any gaps before going back to Sikaflex for a top coat.

Comment: Thanks, what thicker sealant would you recommend? Perhaps the “Sikaflex All Purpose Non-Sag Construction Sealant Polyurethane” which is meant for vertical surfaces so I imagine it’s pretty thick.

Comment: For a thicker sealant, I’d find one with a matching solvent or let them cure for a long time between applications. (Matching solvent = same cleanup instructions.)

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try the vertical grade sealant. Also confirmed with the manufacturer that’s the ideal solution to my problem.